# How to make it so when I select one option, it will show one option and hide the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main dropdown menu and a secondary dropdown menu. When I pick an option in the first dropdown menu, I want a corresponding dropdown menu to appear and when I select another option in the main dropdown menu, for the other corresponding dropdown menu to appear and the previously shown dropdown menu to be hidden.

I have tried using the $attr() function and I think I am using it correctly, but my method isn't working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_dropdown").change(function(){
        let selectedMajor = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (selectedMajor.trim() == 'arts') {
            $("div.custom_select_business").attr("display", "none");
            $('h3').removeAttr('id');
            $("div#hide").removeAttr('id');
            $("div.custom_select_art").removeAttr('id');
        }
        else if (selectedMajor.trim() == 'business') {
            $('h3').removeAttr('id');
            $("div#hide").removeAttr('id');
            $("div.custom_select_business").removeAttr('id');
        }
    });
});
```

I expected it to hide the "business" dropdown menu when I selected the "art" one, but the art dropdown menu just appears and nothing else happens.

Comment: Are you missing some code at the end that didn't copy? Because this is missing some ending brackets and parentheses.

Comment: Ah, I only copy pasted a bit of my code to get the point across. I will update it.

Comment: It might also help to have your HTML code too, just to clarify further. I however, I find that if I attempt to make the simplest example of the function that I am attempting on a space like CodePen.com, I find the solution on my own, especially if it is a matter of troubleshooting. I would help more except that I can only use my mobile device at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this should do what you described, make a main selection, and if it is arts, will show arts, if it is business, will show business, otherwise will hide both.

**CODE >>**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="main" class="main" style="display:block;">
      <label for="artsSelect">main selection</label>
      <select class="mainSelect" name="">
        <option value="hi"> hi </option>
        <option value="arts">arts</option>
        <option value="business">business</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="arts" class="arts" style="display:none;">
      <label for="artsSelect">Arts selection</label>
      <select class="artsSelect" name="">
        <option value="hi"> hi </option>
        <option value="hello">hello</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="business" class="business" style="display:block;">
      <label for="businessSelect">Business selection</label>
      <select class="businessSelect" name="">
        <option value="hi"> hi </option>
        <option value="hello">hello</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="bah">bah</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function(){
      $('.mainSelect').change(function(){
        if($('.mainSelect').val() == "arts"){
          $('#arts').show();
          $('#business').hide();
        }else if($('.mainSelect').val() == "business"){
          $('#arts').hide();
          $('#business').show();
        }else{
          $('#arts').hide();
          $('#business').hide();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```